# Cull empty arrays in a GraphQL query

Tags: graphql

Here's the gist of a GraphQL query to ask for the events of various sports.

```
query Sports {
  sports {
    name
    events {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

We might get back something like:

```
Rugby
  Six Nations
  Rugby Union
Football
  World Cup
  Europe League
...
```

In this situation, it's possible for any sport to have an empty array of events. Is there something I can place in to a query to require that any array should have at least 1 element? Or do I need to implement filtering on clients if I want to prevent this being seen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond requesting specific fields, GraphQL does not have any baked-in means of filtering or reducing the results of a query. Any filtering, sorting, etc. has to be implemented when creating the schema for the endpoint.

You would have to consult the documentation for the endpoint you're using ([or run an introspection query](http://graphql.org/learn/introspection/)) to determine if there are any argument that can be passed to the `sports` field to prevent sports without events from being returned by the server.

Answer (score 0):

In graphCMS we can use keyword "where".
I don't know if this feature is available in the standard API.

```
query Sports {
   sports(where: {events_some: {}}) {
      name
      events {
         name
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it